# Visual Studio Installer 2.9.3349 crashes

Tags: visual-studio

I just did the update of microsoft visual studio installer and now as soon as I open the software, after it appears on the screen the preparation is in progress, the software freezes and after a few seconds it crashes ... Could you tell me how I can fix it? I have already tried to delete the vs installer folder and re-download but nothing to do ....

[It freezes at this screen and after 5 seconds the process stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6CYv.png)

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Stefino76  try to see if it works for you by opening it offline and then, once opened, going back online

Comment: I've test your solution but i can't install anyway. I resolve deleting the folder ProgramData->Microsoft->VisualStudio and then opening the installation file downloaded from internet.  The installation not crashes! Now the installation is complete.